# Gorm UUID foreign key - belongs to

Tags: go, uuid, go-gorm, belongs-to

I'm trying to create a **belongs to** relation between two database tables, using GORM, my code is the following:

```golang
type Shop struct {
    ID    uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid"`
    Name  string    `json:"name" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    City  string    `json:"city" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    State string    `json:"state" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
}
```

```golang
type Employee struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid"`
    FirstName string    `json:"first_name" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    LastName  string    `json:"last_name" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Email     string    `json:"email" gorm:"not null;unique" validate:"required,email"`
    Password  string    `json:"password" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Active    bool      `json:"active" gorm:"not null;default:false"`
    ShopId    uuid.UUID `json:"shop_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Shop      Shop      `gorm:"foreignKey:ShopID"`
}
```

When I run the migrations, this error pops up:

```sh
[error] invalid field found for struct .../.../.../api/models.Employee's field Shop: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

I've found some references using number primary keys and they seem to work fine, but I can't find any solution to work with uuids...

Comment: having a related issue as you can i see your import statement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but what I understand of the message error is that the type `uuid.UUID` doesn't have implemented the methods for the interfaces Valuer and Scanner.

You should create your own type UUID, which can be something like this:

```golang
type UUID uuid.UUID

func(id UUID) Value() (driver.Value, error) {   
    return id.String(), nil
}

func (id *UUID) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    dbID, ok := value.(string)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("id scan: invalid value")
    }
    
    
    *e = uuid.MustParse(dbID)
    return nil
}
```

And use it on your struct's definitions:

```golang
type Shop struct {
    ID    UUID `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid"`
    //...
}
```

Comment: I'm using github.com/satori/go.uuid

Comment: Oh I see, that library has already implemented the Valuer/Scanner, so maybe you should use type `*Shop` on Employee

Comment: and also try `gorm:"foreignKey:ShopId"`

Comment: I just figured out that the problem is the lowercase "d" on "ShopId"... it should be "ShopID". I changed and now the migration worked. But after trying to create a new Employee, I got an error saying that the Shop name is required (because I have the validator rules on Shop struct too). I need to populate the Shop attribute on the Employee struct manually before the validation runs or should GORM do it automatically?

Comment: You need to populate Shop or change the type to `*Shop`,  gorm will ignore it if detects is nil

Comment: Great! It worked with `*Shop`! Thank you so much!